# Remove CSS "content" property

Tags: jquery

I have 3rdparty CSS that contains the following declaration:

```
:-webkit-any(body):after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  font: 0/0;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

The content css property cause a problem in jquery ui dialog - scrollbar disappears...

If i am removing the content (putting in comment) all works well.
Since it is 3rdparty, I would like to remove this property by code via jquery and not updating the css. Is it possible?

Thanks
Sigal

Comment: Why don't you overwrite it with another CSS rule, setting it to `none`?

Comment: I think it is possible... But probably not how you want it to. Can't you for example create another CSS rule file and simply call it after you call the first one? IMO you have two really hard problems to tackle here: the target of that CSS and the timing question to check if that rule has or hasn't been loaded yet. I would simply add another rule to add after the first CSS and save myself the trouble.

Comment: Thanks It works!! (setting to none in a different css file)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about selecting css3 selector as you have mentioned above.but as thiefmaster mentioned,you can overwrite the property.you can set it to none on page load.

1)Using jquery append

```
 $('body').append(":-webkit-any(body):after {content: none;}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged the question [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), but it's important ot know that it is not possible to directly target the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements using javascript.

Your options are:

1. Write additional CSS code that overrides the styles you don't want.
2. Change the original CSS selector (or your HTML) such that the selector no longer applies where you don't want it.

Comment: It is now possible to target the before/after pseudo elements (although IE only gained support in 11). e.g. this gets you the content of `body:after`: `window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').getPropertyValue('content');` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle